# How do i resize images by css in the fixed size block to not look like stretched?

Tags: html, css

In my application profile pictures looks like stretched which is in circle shaped.
And there is rectangle shaped block in which also if the image is of any size other than the block size it looks like stretched.

I found the solution by object-fit:cover; but the problem is by using this, if the images are of small size they are stretching to fit to the block.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please.

Comment: @Anu if despite `object-fit: cover` the image is still stretched, then maybe you should use a bigger image or just reduce the size of the _block_.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes. It is better to use bigger size images and it is fits in the block without stretch but the thing is images are coming dynamically which is in different dimensions that is the problem. If I use object-fit : contain,it solves problem of stretch. But it is taking margins from left and right,if the images are not in aspect ratio. Is there any other solution than object-fit?

Comment: You just have a basic problem if some of the images are too small and of the wrong aspect ratio but you want them to cover a given element's size. Nothing is going to make them look perfect - either you keep them to the max size they can be in the element (contain) which will give margins or you zoom in and cut top/bottom or sides off to fill the element (cover).

Comment: Ok. Thank you I will use object-fit:contain. It is better to use in this case where images not in the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you mean, I think it'll be better if you post some screenshots or codes.

Meanwhile, set max-width, min-width and width to the 100% if they're in the circle frame or you set max-width, min-width and width to the width you want it to be.
If you don't want it stretched/skewed, using "height: auto" will do the magic but to maintain a definite height, set height, min-height and max-height to a definite value.